# Could we have generate inside an always block?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to have sth like this:

```
generate  
   for( i=0 ; i<16 ; i=i+1 ) begin:  
      always @(posedge clk) begin  
         L[i+1] <= #1 R[i];  
         R[i+1] <= #1 L[i] ^ out[i];  
      end  
   end  
endgenerate
```

I would appreciate it if any one could possibly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
always @(posedge clk)
  begin
  L[16:1] <= #1 R[15:0]
  R[16:1] <= #1 L[15:0] ^ out;
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a `generate` here, I think. Just using a `for` loop within the `always` block will work.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin    
   for( int i=0 ; i<16 ; i=i+1 ) begin  
         L[i+1] <= #1 R[i];  
         R[i+1] <= #1 L[i] ^ out[i];  
   end  
end
```

A few questions you'd probably want to think about:

- What size are the `L` and `R` buses? `[15:0]`?
- Where are you assigning values to `L[0]` and `R[0]`?
- Are you sure that `i+1` when `i` hits 15 will be still within the bounds of your bus?

Comment: thanks Marty, i have just one more question, is it synthesizable?

Comment: #1 is not synthesizable but the tool will accept it and simply give you a warning.