# Recursion in Verilog within an Always block

Tags: recursion, verilog

I have a verilog code where I wish to use recursion. However, whenever I try this in an always block, it gives an error saying  is not a task.

Is there any way I can implement a module in an always block? Also is there anyway I can use recursion within the always block?

Comment: Can you give an example of the code? Or explain the algorithm you are trying to implement using recursion? You cannot put a module instance inside an always block.

Comment: The module, multiplies 2 numbers using a complex algorithm. 
One of the steps in the algorithm is to break down the 2 inputs, into smaller numbers and multiply them. I need to use recursion for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write recursive modules using a generate block:

```
module unary_and
#(parameter WIDTH = 32)
(input [WIDTH-1:0] in_and,
output            out_and)

generate
 if(WIDTH == 1) begin
   assign out_and = in_and;
 end
 else if(WIDTH == 2) begin
   assign out_and = in_and[0] & in_and[1];
 end
 else begin
   unary_and #(.WIDTH (WIDTH/2))
     unary_and_low
       (.in_and  (in_and[WIDTH/2-1:0]),
        .out_and (out_and_low));

   unary_and #(.WIDTH (WIDTH - WIDTH/2))
     unary_and_high
       (.in_and  (in_and[WIDTH-1:WIDTH/2]),
        .out_and (out_and_high));

   assign out_and = out_and_low & out_and_high;
 end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

This is from [Recursive and Iterative designs in Verilog](http://jad-reads.blogspot.hu/2009/03/recursive-and-iterative-designs-in.html) where you can find other solutions as well. You can check out [Recursive Modules](http://www.beyond-circuits.com/wordpress/2009/01/recursive-modules/) too.

Maybe you should also take a look at these questions and answers:
[Could we have generate inside an always block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553097/could-we-have-generate-inside-an-always-block)
[Verilog generate/genvar in an always block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504837/verilog-generate-genvar-in-an-always-block)